# PHP using next() to display each name upon button click

Tags: php, indexing

I am trying to display each name of an array in order with a 'Next' button and 'Previous' button. I can reference the next indexed part of the array but cannot go on farther than the first associated index. The same is true for the previous button.

Here is my code:

```
$people = array("Peter", "Joe", "Glenn", "Cleveland");

echo "<br>";

$current_people = current($people);

echo $current_people;


if(isset($_POST['Next'])) {

// this only prints out Joe, does nothing if clicked again
    echo next($people);
}

if(isset($_POST['Previous'])) {
    echo prev($people);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memory is not persisted between requests in most PHP setups.  In these setups, you'll have an entirely new instance of your array for each HTTP request that your service handles.  Therefore, all your requests will start at the beginning of the array.

In a stateless API design, you would most likely include the current position as part of the request, I.E. position 0 on the first request, position 1 on the second request.  The client maintains the current state and you use that state to determine what position to read from in the server's array.

Comment: Would using a $_SESSION work?

Comment: Yes, you could use a session as an alternative to a stateless design.